# PyCharm 2018.3.2 cannot import numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I use

Anaconda3-5.3.1-Windows-x86_64

pycharm-professional-2018.3.2

When I run a python code, I get:

```
"Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

Could I ask you guys that what is the problem? How to solve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: did you try `pip install numpy`? Did you specify the correct Interpreter in PyCharm?

Comment: Interpreter is correct.

pip install numpy does not solve the issue.

I think something wrong with pycharm

Comment: So numpy is listed in your interpreters installed packages? Check this in File > Settings > Project: > Project Interpreter

Comment: Hi! You might want to check out this website on how to install packages in PyCharm (since I believe it is different from vanilla python): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html

Comment: all packages were installed properly

Comment: Which package raises this error? Does `import numpy` work? Also which version of Python/numpy/the library that causes the error do you use?
Finally if you use Anaconda, I suggest using `conda` to install the packages rather than `pip` when possible.

Comment: Sounds like a known issue in PyCharm https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-32366

Comment: the numpy works fine in jupyter notebook and in spyder.

Answer (score 2):

"**It is a bug being fixed for PyCharm 2018**"
On Windows 10, Pycharm 2018.x.x versions, give this dependency error. Some people have reported this error when using pyCharm on Window 7 too.

Here is hack around to resolve this temporarily, until new release fixes this bug.

**Solution**

1. Download this EAP from the below website i.e. PyCharm 2019.1 or higher: [https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ozQR.png)
2. Additionally, if your are using Python 3.7, revert back to Python 3.6 so that it works.

**Scrrenshot:**:
[Steps showing PyCharm python version control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ozQR.png)

*References:*

1. https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2019/02/pycharm-2019-1-eap-3/
2. https://github.com/uber/ludwig/issues/108

Cheers
CH